# I cant display my data in a forloop in a cakephp3 view

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I cannot display any of my data from the array in the view. I have no idea why as I seem to follow the conventions.It is the same error with each field.
I display the data in the debug below so it it is just an array of table values.  How do i display the array of data from the below array given in a view ? Note I just gave a sample data of the 1st record only as there is too much data in the array to display

```
Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object 
  <?php 
            foreach ($query3 as $bookmark):
            ?>
            <tr>
                <?php 
              debug( $bookmark);
                ?>

                <td><?= h($bookmark->lessons->id) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($bookmark->lessons->lesson_date) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($bookmark->tutors->first_name) ?></td>
                 <td><?= h($bookmark->tutors->last_name) ?></td>


            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>



object(App\Model\Entity\Lesson) {

    'tutoring_type_id' => (int) 1,
    'students' => [
        'id' => '249',
        'first_name' => 'Jams',
        'last_name' => 'Phil'
    ],
    'tutoring_type' => object(App\Model\Entity\TutoringType) {

        'value' => 'Individual Tuition',
        '[new]' => false,
        '[accessible]' => [
            '*' => true
        ],
        '[dirty]' => [],
        '[original]' => [],
        '[virtual]' => [],
        '[errors]' => [],
        '[invalid]' => [],
        '[repository]' => 'TutoringTypes'

    },
    'lessons' => [
        'id' => '12419',
        'lesson_date' => '2016-05-31'
    ],
    'tutors' => [
        'id' => '12',
        'first_name' => 'drew',
        'last_name' => 'Toy'
    ],
    'subjects' => [
        'id' => '16',
        'name' => 'Maths: Year 7 - 10'
    ],
    'terms' => [
        'id' => '12',
        'title' => 'Term Four - 2015'
    ],

UPDATE
     $query3 = $this->Lessons->find()
              ->contain(['Tutors','Subjects', 'TutoringTypes','Terms','Students'])
              ->select(['lessons.id','lessons.lesson_date','tutors.id','tutors.first_name','tutors.last_name','TutoringTypes.value',
                  'subjects.id','subjects.name'])      
               ->where(['Lessons.lesson_date >' => $a3
                   ]);


 $this->set(compact('query3'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['query3']);
```

Comment: `students` and `lessons` seem to be arrays and not objects. So you should do `$bookmark->lessons['id']`. I don't know why you have arrays instead of objects, you should show your `find()` code

Comment: I have already answered this below and it works. I couldnt find this information in the docs and I gave the array of data. I have just also gave the find() if it helps(look in question at the bottom).. What do you mean I should have used objects? I cant find this information in the docs can you show me please

Comment: I checked the docs on collections. I simply wanted to display the results in a view so I used an array. If I wanted to use further methods on the query then I would need the query object and not an array,

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and i coudnt find this in the docs.
It works but if there is a better way then please correct it.

```
   <td><?= $bookmark->lessons['id'] ?></td>
   <td><?= $bookmark->lessons['lesson_date'] ?></td>
   <td><?= $bookmark->tutors['first_name'] ?></td>
   <td><?= $bookmark->tutors['last_name'] ?></td>
   <td><?= $bookmark->subjects['name'] ?></td>
```

The other way is to use an object set returned in the query. Even after asking experts on how to do this I still get marked down by some. Where is this in the docs?

```
$query3 = $this->Lessons->find()
              ->contain(['Tutors','Subjects', 'TutoringTypes','Terms','Students'])
              ->select(['Lessons.id','Lessons.lesson_date','Tutors.id','Tutors.first_name','Tutors.last_name',
                  'Subjects.name','TutoringTypes.value'])     
               ->where(['Lessons.lesson_date ' => $a3
                   ]);
          $query3->hydrate(true);


            $query3->matching('Students', function ($q) use ($a8) {

                 return $q
                    ->select(['Students.id','Students.first_name','Students.last_name']) 
                  ->where(['Students.first_name like' =>'%'.$a8.'%']);
                });
```

in the view

```
            <td><?= $bookmark->id ?></td>
            <td><?= $bookmark->lesson_date ?></td>
            <td><?= $bookmark->tutor->first_name ?></td>
            <td><?= $bookmark->tutor->last_name ?></td>

             <td><?= $bookmark->students[0]->first_name ?></td>
             <td><?= $bookmark->students[0]->last_name ?></td>
             <td><?= $bookmark->subject->name ?></td>
             <td><?= $bookmark->tutoring_type->value ?></td>
```

Comment: add information in your question about how you create your find() call. Seems related to your [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37716863/different-output-for-model-name-with-capital-letter-in-cakephp3) question but it's hard to tell since we don't know much about your relationships and your queries

Comment: Where is this information on the docs you are talking about?  I couldnt find it myself so what am I supposed to do?I did use bake and I didnt guess the syntax correctly either.

Comment: @AD7six seems that the user opened other 2 questions about basically the same problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37716863/different-output-for-model-name-with-capital-letter-in-cakephp3) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37714749/i-cant-display-fields-from-a-table-with-an-underscore-in-cakephp3). Somehow his DBMS is case insensitive and does not gives error when he writes `lessons` instead of `Lessons` but cake returns an array instead of an object. Don't know if this is the desidered behavior, a bug or whatever.

Comment: @AD7six ok, but now I'm just beeing curious: as you see in the `find()` call at the bottom of the OP he uses camelCase inside the `contain()` method, but lowercase in the `select()` method. i.e `contain(['Tutors', ...])` but `select(['tutors.id', ...])`. Normally in mysql this would give an error. Instead he gets a result when instead of objects there are arrays. Apart for `tutoring_type` that is an object and in fact he selected `'TutoringTypes.value'` (camelCase). This is at least strange (at least for me)

Comment: Guys to be frank, I am grateful for your help but as yet you cant point me to any relevant documentation l. ALL I want to do is simply get data from a query and then simply display it. It is dead simple. The issue is the docs are not clear on how to display queries from associated tables I cant display data when I have a capital letter for model names . I am not clear on whether to have a captial letter for each model in the query select. As for objects or arrays, again I dont get why i get arrays from the query result.

Comment: I would really really like some information on cakephp3 docs that can explain display data from associated tables  this instead of trying to ask questions.